# Can we use AND and OR in Java instead of && and ||?

Tags: java, conditional-statements, pipe

I know we can in PHP but I can't find anything for Java

```
if (bool1 AND bool2) {...}
```

instead of :

```
if (bool1 && bool2) {...}
```

Comment: Long answer: noooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo.

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, you have to use `&&`/`||` to check the first condition and if it is false, it won't even check the second. If you use `&`/`|` it will check both regardless of the first one.